# In $\triangle ABC$, $|PA| \le |PB| + |PC|$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

**Problem:** In $\triangle ABC$, $|BC|$ is longest side. $P$ is a point in the plane of $\triangle ABC$. Prove that $$ |PB|+|PC| \ge |PA|$$ and determine equality conditions.

**Notes:**
I aimed to present this problem, the solution of which I know, to the benefit of the users, as it has an aesthetic aspect. I also shared the question to learn about different possible solutions myself. It is not made in a spirit like challenging to users. It is a post to contribute to accumulation that may benefit the community.

(For these reasons, I would appreciate if the problem is unblocked.)

Comment: Sorry but, this is not simple triangle inequality.

Comment: @DHMO: the triangle inequality only gives that the LHS is $\geq |BC|$, so if the inequality is achieved, it is achieved outside the circle centered at $A$ with radius $|BC|$.

Comment: Oops, I responded too fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Ptolemy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_inequality), 
$$ PA \cdot BC \le PB \cdot AC + PC \cdot AB. $$
Taking into account $BC \ge AC$ and $BC \ge AB$, we get the desired inequality.

Equality holds if and only if $A,B,C,P$ are cocyclic (that's the equality condition for Ptolemy's inequality) and $BC = AC$, $BC = AB$. In other words, if the triangle $ABC$ is equilateral and $P$ lies on its circumcircle.

Comment: Michał Miśkiewicz, thanks for your solution. Can you give equality conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $AP\cap BC=\{K\}$.

Thus,
$$AP<AK\leq\max\{AB,AC\}\leq BC<BP+CP$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort Michael Rozenberg. Your solution valids when only $P$ is interior of $\triangle ABC$. If $P$ is out side of  $\triangle ABC$ then, $AP > AK$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you! The Michał Miśkiewicz's solution is true and beautiful.